# Not able to connect from Spring Boot Docker Container to Local MySQL Database Server

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I am working on Windows 10 Environment.
My Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474.

**I have a Spring Boot application running on Docker container
I am trying to access local instance of MySQL from Spring Application. My instance of MYSQL is not running on container.**

> I understand this is a networking issue and already try to run docker
>   using following command : docker run -p 8282:8191 ami --network="host"
>   but no success.

Can somebody please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Note : My Spring application configuration is fine as i am able to connect AWS MSQL RDS server from container without any issue.

#### The error I am receiving as below

```
2019-04-19 07:33:32.025  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3308 ms
2019-04-19 07:33:32.264  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-04-19 07:33:33.422 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

#### Few Information :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/financedb
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker for Windows uses a vm to run Linux containers. The “localhost” is therefore the vm and not your windows machine when running with net=host 
You can use the special host name as MySQL host

docker.for.win.localhost

This points to your windows machine and you can even run without net=host.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please give me some reference or some guidance how to map special host name in docker ..please

Comment: The special host name is provided by Docker on windows / Mac automatically.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. it helps me .. Only change i have to do ..to up-grade my docker version. Thanks again .. It is working now ..

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker.for.win.localhost:3306/financedb

Comment: Any idea about how to use this in Linux? we used `localhost`, but it was not working.